# Is it possible to have non-compact, embedded submanifold (without boundary) of a closed manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Sorry if my question is elementary, I've not touched differential geometry/topology for a while: my question is: is it possible to have a non-compact, embedded submanifold $S$ without boundary of a closed manifold $M?$ If yes, can both $S, M$ be smooth? I'm thinking of a one dimensional such submanifold of the two torus.

Or is there a theorem that says that any non-compact, embedded submanifold $S$ without boundary of a closed manifold $M$ must be closed?

Comment: Do you require an embedded submanifold to be closed? If so, a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Comment: If not, you can embed $\mathbb{R}$ into the circle with open (non-closed) image, say the open half semicircle.

Comment: Every manifold admits an embedding into some $\mathbb{R}^n$, which embeds into $\mathbb{S}^n$.